# SQL inserting variables from different statements

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

```
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("DECLARE @ControlPaneliD int");
    sb.Append(" SET @ControlPaneliD=(SELECT ControlPanelID");
    sb.Append(" FROM ControlPanelID");
    sb.Append(" WHERE Name=@Name)");

    sb.Append("DECLARE @UserName UniqueIdentifier");
    sb.Append(" SET @UserName=(SELECT Name");
    sb.Append(" FROM UsersID");
    sb.Append(" WHERE UsersID=@UserID)");

    sb.Append("INSERT INTO dbo.CP_Comments (ControlPanelID,Comments,Commentator)");
    sb.Append(" VALUES(@ControlPaneliD,@Comment,@UserName)");
    MembershipUser CurrentUser = Membership.GetUser();
    Guid id = (Guid)CurrentUser.ProviderUserKey;

    string myConnectionString = AllQuestionsPresented.connectionString;
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(AllQuestionsPresented.connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sb.ToString(), conn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("UserID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = id;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("Comment", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = name; //string variable from my code
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
```

I am trying to do two select statements, put their results in their variables and insert their variables plus another variable into another insert statement..

I am not sure if I am doing it right, I would appreciate your help if you gave me some advice and some criticism on what I composed

Comment: BTW, are you aware of 'verbatim string literals? You don't need all those Append's.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090.aspx.

Comment: @VladV: but concatenating together this statement using simple strings will hell - each time you add something to a string variable, a new string is created. Using a StringBuilder in such a case **IS** the recommended way of doing it

Comment: @marc_s: I meant something like string query = @"DECLARE @ControlPaneliD int <line break here>
SET @ControlPaneliD=(SELECT ControlPanelID ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method looks OK but it is recommended that you use stored procedure instead of passing query

Comment: hmmm.. why cant I use an inline code?/// What difference does it make if i pass the Textbox1 variable to store procedure or to an inline sql code?

Comment: 1.As Nico said below that sql injection threat increases using inline code.
2.Using of Store Procedure is best practice
3.Store Procedure prevents from sql injection as u can assign roles on store procedure from your database

Comment: omg..but all my sql inline code is inline not in stored procedure.. :(

Comment: Store Procedure is pre compiled as inline code first compiled tan execute so chances of error increases

Comment: Don,t worry if you can,t convert your inline code to store procedure make validations as strong as you can

Comment: @Shoaib Muhammad Khan: Actually, inline queries reuse execution plans almost as well as SPs do. And they could reuse the plans even with different parameter values, thanks to auto-parametrization.
And, in real life, compilation time is almost always negligible, so you shouldn't care too much about it.

Answer (score 2):

1. In insert statement you inserting 3 parameters into 2 columns.
2. I think you should write stored procedure and pass parameters for it. You always "generating" sql code with string builder. And to change some functionality in stored procedure is much easier than find statement in code, change it and rebuild app.
3. `SELECT ControlPanelID FROM ControlPanelID WHERE Name=@Name` and `SELECT Name FROM UsersID WHERE UsersID=@UserID` looks strange. Do you really have tables with names `ControlPanelID` and `UsersID`?

Comment: It works I tried it.. I have a class of static functions, they take parameters and put them into a database..their is no mess.. I prefer do it through inlne code.. But if security is concerned..then i dont know...I guess it makes the inline code completely redundant!!!

Answer (score 1):

This is really vulnerable to SQL-injection, especially this part:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("Comment", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
```

This is very, very dangerous. I cannot imagine you haven't heard about this, but just in case, check out this wiki article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

If you really want/ need to execute raw SQL, always escape the values.

Have you considered using a strongly typed DAL like LINQ2SQL, DataEntities etc?

Comment: They are too slow;;;linq2sql and data entities

Comment: Why is this dangerous? It's using a SQL parameter, not code breaks?

Comment: You are absolutely right, parameters are not vulnerable to SQL injection. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather suggest putting that code in a stored procedure.  Its not a good idea to put that in a string builder and execute it.